# How can I download files given api... and urls?

Tags: html, r, readr

I want to download the files at https://data.gov.hk/en-data/dataset/hk-dh-chpsebcddr-novel-infectious-agent/resource/a09134c1-53ea-4916-a573-62cf972562af. I selected the date range from December 31, 2019 until April 13, 2020. I see the links like these there:

https://api.data.gov.hk/v1/historical-archive/get-file?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv&time=20200411-0928

https://api.data.gov.hk/v1/historical-archive/get-file?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv&time=20200412-0945

https://api.data.gov.hk/v1/historical-archive/get-file?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv&time=20200413-0946

How can I download 10s or 100s of files from these links using R? Simple read_* function will not read these file. I  don't have a code to share here as I don't know how to attempt this?

Comment: `d = readr::read_csv("https://api.data.gov.hk/v1/historical-archive/get-file?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv&time=20200411-0928")` works for me. When you say *"Simple read_\* function will not read these file"*, can you explain more? Do you get an error or a warning? What does it say? Something else goes wrong?

Comment: `download.file("https://api.data.gov.hk/v1/historical-archive/get-file?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chp.gov.hk%2Ffiles%2Fmisc%2Fenhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv&time=20200411-0928", destfile = file.path(getwd(), "a.csv"))` works fine. What did you try?

Comment: OMG, I am so silly! I used to think, I could only use the url part i.e. http%3A%2F%2... and to treat the api...., I need something special. Did not realize I should have included the entire thing.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example.

```
raw <- readr::read_csv("http://www.chp.gov.hk/files/misc/enhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv",
                       col_names = TRUE)

head(raw)
# A tibble: 6 x 10
# [...]
```

And here is a more complete example saving downloaded file under `/data-raw` as stated in the book *[R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)*.

```
file_name <- "enhanced_sur_covid_19_eng.csv"
url <- stringr::str_glue("http://www.chp.gov.hk/files/misc/{file_name}")
raw_data <- stringr::str_glue("data-raw/{file_name}")
reload <- FALSE

if (reload | !file.exists(raw_data)) {
    download.file(url, raw_data)
}

raw <- readr::read_csv(raw_data,
                       col_names = TRUE)

head(raw)
# A tibble: 6 x 10
# [...]
```